# "Exception: std::bad_alloc" when importing rasterio in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, qgis-plugins, rasterio

While importing rasterio in QGIS is showing `Exception: std::bad_alloc`

[image: Qgis Screenshot]

When I re-import rasterio afterwards it shows error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 63, in runsource
    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codeop.py", line 178, in __call__
    return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codeop.py", line 106, in _maybe_compile
    raise err1
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codeop.py", line 93, in _maybe_compile
    code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codeop.py", line 143, in __call__
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, 1)
  File "<input>", line 1
    import rasterio
                  ^
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
```

Python: 3.8.10
rasterio: 1.2.10
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS  .
I installed QGIS by `apt`, and rasterio by `pip`.

Comment: i tried uninstalling rasterio and reinstalling, it does'nt helped.

Comment: How exactly did you install, using `pip install rasterio` or `pip3 install rasterio` or `python3 -m pip install rasterio`?

Comment: Initially i reinstalled by ```pip install rasterio``` but now i also tried                                      ```sudo apt install python3-rasterio```  it also didn't worked.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz any update?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Do you get the same error when using the python in terminal?

Comment: No, on terminal the code runs perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it didn't really come from rasterio but pyproj.
Check this link:

https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#internal-proj-error-sqlite-error-on-select

In my case, qgis was installed with apt and so the pyproj package came from apt. But at the same time I had something like this in my code:

toto.py

```py
from A.common.wms import WMS
```

A/common/src/wms.py

```py
import pyproj

class WMS: 
   pass
```

"A.common" is a package that I have installed with pip in the user environment (somewhere in .local for linux). So it means that qgis tried to import pyproj from the user site package while it was probably imported previously. Even if it was not imported, I mixed different version of pyproj and it was not good.